# Swift 5 if camera in use

Tags: swift, xcode

How can i check if the iPhone back camera is in use with Swift 5+ and then turn on my the flashlight while the camera is running i got my function to turn on the flash but don't know how to access the camera status?

```
func toggleTorch() {
        guard
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video),
            device.hasTorch
        else { return }

        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            if device.torchMode == AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.on
            {
                device.torchMode = .off
                
            } else {
                device.torchMode = .on
                
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print("Torch could not be used")
        }
    }
```

And i have tried with this:

```
  var cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position!
    func switchCamera() {
        switch cameraPosition {
        case .back:
            cameraPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.front
            print(cameraPosition)
        case .front:
            cameraPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.back
            toggleTorch()
        default:
            cameraPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.front
            print(cameraPosition)

        }
      }
```

Comment: Do you mean https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619159-iscameradeviceavailable ?

Comment: No not quite i want the flashlight to turn on as soon as camera opens in "video mode" therefore i found i easy just to look for if the camera is in use rightnow

Comment: On an iPhone how can you not know if the camera is in use? You would be the one using it.

Comment: Right, as @matt is saying - tracking the camera being on or off could be easier than trying to detect it. Whenever you turn it on or off, update a variable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.